# How to click button to show time in Timepicker plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a button and I want to press button, it'll be display panel to choose time in Timepicker plugin. I can do it with pressing textbox and now I want to press a button. This's plugin

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Here my code:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Set Time" id="S-Time"/><button>Click to show</button>

<script>
$('#S-Time').timepicker();
</script>
```

Comment: You should be able to reuse the code for the textbox, with the button. Without a code sample it's difficult to help.

Comment: since this plugin supports all option in jqueryUI's  Datepicker, you can use these options to add a image button: `showOn: "button", buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif", buttonImageOnly: true`

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$('#S-Time').timepicker();
$('button').click(function(){
    $('#S-Time').focus();
});
```

Comment: @NathanNguyễn If it works then please mark one of our answers as correct for the next user. Arun's answer is also correct.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Set Time" id="S-Time"/><button id="S-Time-Show">Click to show</button>

  $('#S-Time').datetimepicker();

  $('#S-Time-Show').click(function(){ //your button
    $('#S-Time').focus();
  });
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ASvFFs54mmdVsBFiAY2K?p=preview)